# remove object from NSMutableArray that contains NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray of NSArray's inside it. This is my current structure:

```
    Paused index (
       (
          0,
          3579
       ),
       (
          1,
          3538
       )
    )
```

how to search through the array and remove the object 3538? My expected result is:

```
    Paused index (
       (
          0,
          3579
       )
    )
```

How can I get the index of the outer array? I can already do the search but how can I remove the object in that index?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the search?

Comment: sorry for the misleading question. I want to remove the object, I already do the search now I want to remove it.

Comment: [yourMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:theIndex];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very straight forward way.

```
    NSArray *firstArray =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000], nil];
NSArray *secondArray =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5000], nil];

NSMutableArray *arrayWithArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:firstArray,secondArray,nil];
int i = 0;

for (NSArray *innerArray in arrayWithArray) 
{
    if ([innerArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5000]])
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;

}
NSLog(@"Index of object %d",i);
[arrayWithArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
```

Some other intelligent way should be there.

EDIT:
I think this is little better.

```
int i = [arrayWithArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id element,NSUInteger idx,BOOL *stop)
    {
       return [(NSArray *)element containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5000]];
    }];

    NSLog(@"Index of object %d",i);
    if (i >= 0 && i < [arrayWithArray count]) 
    {
         [arrayWithArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

Comment: why do you use for-in statement and counter i at once? for(;;) statement is be more appropriate for this situation? I don't know how it works in objective-C but it is a bad practice in other languages because for-in statement may look over each element with no order in general

Comment: is it?. I never know. In objective-c it always follows the order.No way to confirm though. what you makes sense. Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: The similar situation is when you use goto and if operators instead of cycle operator. It is possible but they don't advise to write such code

Answer (score 0):

As you have this array

Array_Paused_index 
(

```
   (
      0,
      3579
   ),
   (
      1,
      3538
   )
```

)

Take one more Array

Array = [Array_Paused_index  objectAtIndex: 0];

Result will be

Array

(

```
 (

   0,

   3579

 )
```

)

OR SECOND METHOD :

[Array_Paused_index removeObjectAtIndex:1];